# How to set the subject line and add attachment while using sendmail utility on linux?

Tags: linux, sendmail

I am using sendmail utility on CentOs to send mail. I am not able to set the subject-line and add attachment for the mails which are sent using this utility. Using option "-s" to set the subject line is not applicable for sendmail utility. Please tell what options to use with the sendmail for achieving thses objectives.

Comment: To those that vote to close this question because it is about a tool and not about programming, I disagree. `sendmail` is a tool intended to be used by other programs, not manually by the users. As such it can be considered a kind of old-fashioned dynamic-like module, only that in executable format instead of shared object. And as such, IMO, the `sendmail` interface is on-topic in SO.

Answer (score 9):

`sendmail` is a low-level utility. You have to compose the extra message headers yourself.

That is, to add the subject line, before the body of the message you prepend:

```
Subject: <your-subject>
```

And a new line to separate the headers from the body.

Likewise, to add the attachment:

```
Subject: <your-subject>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-unique-str"

---unique-str
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline

<html-body here>
---unique-str
Content-Type: application; name=<attachment-mime>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<attachment-name>

<your base64-encoded attachment here>
---unique-str--
```

Or something like this (I didn't test it).

You can see how real messages are formatted by looking at the "show original" or "show source" options available in most e-mail clients. Those options will show you the raw-message and you just need to build something similar.

Comment: Isn't it possible to set the subject header using some option so that it can be set in command-line. Like I want send the mail this way..../usr/sbin/sendmail -v amit@abc.com < MailBody.txt. Can you tell me how i set the subject here in this command line

Comment: @Amit: No command-line option that I know of. But you can do `( echo "Subject: hello there"; echo; cat MailBody.txt ) | sendmail -v amit@abc.com`. Or you cound add the subject line and the empty line to the `MailBody.txt` file, if you write the contents yourself.

Comment: Hi rodrigo,......can you please tell how to add a file as attachment and putting some email ids in CC while using sendmail utility. and Is it possible to change the "From" mail-id while sending mail because normally its having some other mail-id as "from" to which if recepient responds, I won;t be able to see their reply. I want to set a email-id from which mail seems to be coming to all recepient.

Comment: @Amit: You can add whatever SMTP headers you want to the input of sendmail. If you use `-t` then even the `To:` headers can be used. About the attachment, that would be too long to add here. You should look around in the Internet (there are several examples) or try asking another question.